# SELECT after WHERE with LINQ Lambda In VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, select

So I am having a hell of a time trying to figure out how to finish up this query statement I am working in LINQ on VB.Net.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
Sub Part_Search(iData As List(Of String), ByRef dataGrid As DataGridView)
    Dim query = From p In db.Parts
                Join s In db.Suppliers On s.Supplier_ID Equals p.Supplier_ID
                Join sc In db.Parts_Category_Subs On sc.Subcategory_ID Equals p.Subcategory_ID
    For i = 0 To iData.Count - 1
        If Not iData(i).ToString() = "" Then
            Select Case i
                Case 0
                    Dim partNum As String = iData(i).ToString()
                    query = query.Where(Function(x) x.p.Part_Number = partNum)
                Case 1
                    Dim description As String = iData(i).ToString()
                    query = query.Where(Function(x) x.p.Part_Description = description)
                Case 4
                    Dim supp As String = iData(i).ToString()
                    query = query.Where(Function(x) x.s.Supplier_Name = supp)
            End Select
        End If
    Next
    'SELECT STATEMENT HERE
    dataGrid.DataSource = query.ToList()
End Sub
```

So, now an explanation of what the heck it was I just posted above.

I have a Windows Form that has a bunch of different input elements (TextBoxes, and ComboBoxes) that the user is suppose to be able to use to search a parts database.  The method above is my method which runs the query once the user has pressed the Search Button.

The `iData` String List that is passed is a List comprised of whatever values are in the input fields when the button is pressed.  The list will even contain empty values, so each specific index of the list will always be associated with a specific table column.  For example, the very first value in the List will **always** be the `Part_Number` field.  This is why I chose to use a Select statement, inside of the iteration loop.  It seemed like the easiest way to easily run through every input value.

Anyway, right now the code runs fine, but what I am returning is every Column of my Parts table.  What I want to display is:

- Part_Number & Part_Description [Parts Table]
- Supplier_Name [Suppliers Table]
- Subcategory_Description [Parts_Category_Subs Table]

My problem is I can't figure out how to properly program a Lambda `Select()` statement for my query.  I have tried:

```
query = query.Select(Function(x) New With { x.p.Part_Number, x.p.Part_Description, x.s.Supplier_Name, x.sc.Subcategory_Description })
```

As well as a few other things, but I am either getting errors in the debugger, or during operation.

So how exactly do I program this Select statement?  I can't seem to make heads or tails off of any information I am finding online on how to get this to work.

EDIT: Adding it on to here instead of making a new question, but I am having a new error that is wierding me out.  So as I stated above, *before* I was able to run this method with submitted data and have it just display all the rows of the `Parts` Table.

However, suddenly, running the program again The columns I am seeing are titled on my 3 query variables `p, s, sc` and each data row reads as: `AppName.ColumnName`.  For example the `p` column is reading as `AppName.Part`.  This change happened without me making any code changes, when everything was working fine before.  So what the heck just happened?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after a few hours of searching for a solution...well I feel kind of silly.
My solution was to basically change this:

```
Dim query = From p In db.Parts
            Join s In db.Suppliers On s.Supplier_ID Equals p.Supplier_ID
            Join sc In db.Parts_Category_Subs On sc.Subcategory_ID Equals p.Subcategory_ID
```

To this:

```
Dim query = From p In db.Parts
            Join s In db.Suppliers On s.Supplier_ID Equals p.Supplier_ID
            Join sc In db.Parts_Category_Subs On sc.Subcategory_ID Equals p.Subcategory_ID
            Select p.Part_Number, p.Part_Description, s.Supplier_Name, sc.Subcategory_Description
```

My issue was I was missing the `Select` statement in the initial declaration of the query.

I think this mistake was because in my head, I know that if I was actually typing up a query I would need to put any `Where` clauses before the `Select` statement.  However because the query isn't executed until the `query.ToList()` part of the code, every time I add a `Where` statement in my `Select Case` block, the program essentially rewrites the query and places it before the Select.

Something to keep in mind for anyone in the future who may be having a similar issue!

Comment: And also you should keep in mind that when you properly design your database with all the relations in place, you "very rarely" need to use "join" keyword in Linq. Instead you simply refer using "dot notation" - ie: p.Supplier.Supplier_Name.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I did not know this.  You just exploded my brain.